# отправка сообщения в беседу через юзера с полем payload

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Можно ли как то отправить через vk_api сообщение в беседу с полем payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Только что проверил с токеном пользователя, отправил запрос [`messages.send`](https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.send) с полем *payload* и получил это поле через запрос [`messages.getHistory`](https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.getHistory).

Вот такой ответ я получил по методу `messages.getHistory`

```json
{
  "response": {
    "count": 373
    "items": [
      {
        "date": 1677317385
        "from_id": 248525108
        "id": 2272618
        "out": 1
        "attachments": []
        "conversation_message_id": 991
        "fwd_messages": []
        "important": false
        "is_hidden": false
        "payload": "42"
        "peer_id": 248525108
        "random_id": 0
        "text": "hi"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```